# Qt/QML application crashes when using webengine in debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

When running one of the examples using `webengine` (quicknanobrowser for instance), the project runs in release mode, but I get a crash when trying to run in debug mode.

Here is the backtrace, I get within qtcreator.

> Starting
>   D:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.11.0\webengine\build-quicknanobrowser-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\debug\quicknanobrowser.exe...
>
> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
>
> [16204:11860:0528/174814.316:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1832)] Destroying
>   invalid entry.
>
> [16204:11860:0528/174814.316:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1832)] Destroying
>   invalid entry.
>
> [16204:7912:0528/174814.361:FATAL:simple_watcher.cc(137)] Check
>   failed: task_runner_->RunsTasksInCurrentSequence().
>
> Backtrace:
>
> GetHandleVerifier [0x0000000182B7E3E5+502837]
>
> GetHandleVerifier [0x0000000182B928F8+586056]
>
> QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::_q_destroyedUrlSchemeHandler
>   [0x0000000182A85430+3552]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::BrowserContextAdapter::isOffTheRecord
>   [0x0000000183BFB280+898992]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::BrowserContextAdapter::isOffTheRecord
>   [0x0000000183BD9392+760002]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::BrowserContextAdapter::isOffTheRecord
>   [0x0000000183BD7042+750962]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::BrowserContextAdapter::isOffTheRecord
>   [0x0000000183BCA29A+698314]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::BrowserContextAdapter::isOffTheRecord
>   [0x0000000183BC2384+665780]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::JavaScriptDialogController::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00000001801D21FC+69644]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::JavaScriptDialogController::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00000001801D2963+71539]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::JavaScriptDialogController::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00000001801D2946+71510]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::JavaScriptDialogController::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x00000001801D1D03+68371]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FaviconManager::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x0000000181BBCBB3+2910355]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FaviconManager::qt_static_metacall
>   [0x0000000181BBE3B8+2916504]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x000000018340405F+7213039]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x0000000183404520+7214256]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x000000018340579D+7218989]
>
> QWebEngineCookieStorePrivate::q_func [0x00000001862E102B+1833963]
>
> IsSandboxedProcess [0x00000001856A4CB3+14681795]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::UserScript::validUserScriptSchemes
>   [0x0000000183890905+1042949]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::UserScript::validUserScriptSchemes
>   [0x0000000183893301+1053697]
>
> base::RefCountedThreadSafe
>
> > ::RefCountedThreadSafe
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x000000018358BB96+8817446]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x000000018358D654+8824292]
>
> QWebEngineCookieStorePrivate::q_func [0x00000001862E102B+1833963]
>
> IsSandboxedProcess [0x00000001856A4CB3+14681795]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::UserScript::validUserScriptSchemes
>   [0x0000000183890905+1042949]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::UserScript::validUserScriptSchemes
>   [0x0000000183893301+1053697]
>
> base::RefCountedThreadSafe
>
> > ::RefCountedThreadSafe
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x00000001833FEDDB+7191915]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x00000001833FF2FE+7193230]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x00000001833FE155+7188709]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x00000001833FFA57+7195111]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x00000001833FF6EE+7194238]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x0000000183378282+6640146]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x000000018342B12F+7372991]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x0000000183679172+9789698]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x000000018367BEFC+9801356]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x0000000183679ACF+9792095]
>
> QWebEngineCookieStorePrivate::q_func [0x00000001862E102B+1833963]
>
> IsSandboxedProcess [0x00000001856A4CB3+14681795]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::UserScript::validUserScriptSchemes
>   [0x0000000183890905+1042949]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::UserScript::validUserScriptSchemes
>   [0x0000000183893301+1053697]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::PdfiumDocumentWrapperQt::pageCount
>   [0x0000000182A0073A+1516282]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x0000000183561C25+8645557]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x000000018356721B+8667563]
>
> CertificateErrorController::overridable [0x0000000180CF922A+7620650]
>
> IsSandboxedProcess [0x0000000184AF8476+2440838]
>
> IsSandboxedProcess [0x0000000184AF8598+2441128]
>
> IsSandboxedProcess [0x0000000184AF92B1+2444481]
>
> base::RefCountedThreadSafe
>
> > ::RefCountedThreadSafe
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x0000000183662339+9695945]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x0000000183667484+9716756]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::WebEngineSettings::setUnknownUrlSchemePolicy
>   [0x00000001815E7947+7732663]
>
> base::RefCountedThreadSafe
>
> > ::AddRef [0x0000000185839249+966089]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x0000000183594565+8852725]
>
> QtWebEngineCore::FilePickerController::mode
>   [0x000000018359F1E1+8896881]
>
> base::RefCountedThreadSafe
>
> > ::RefCountedThreadSafe
>
> QtWebEngineCore::UserScript::validUserScriptSchemes
>   [0x000000018387AC99+953753]
>
> CertificateErrorController::overridable [0x0000000180CF922A+7620650]
>
> IsSandboxedProcess [0x0000000184AF8476+2440838]
>
> IsSandboxedProcess [0x0000000184AF8598+2441128]
>
> The program has unexpectedly finished.
>
> The process was ended forcefully.
>
> D:/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.11.0/webengine/build-quicknanobrowser-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug/debug/quicknanobrowser.exe
>   crashed.

Anyone has a clue of what is going on?

Comment: The Line 'QML debugging is enabled' says. when you release any code the Debugging must be disabled. Please do it and it should help.

Comment: I get this crash in debug mode, release is ok. I try to turn off the "Enable QML debugging and profiling" and get the same crash, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try enabling "safe environment" with debugging enabled.

Comment: I can not find "safe environment" option in Qt Creator. Can you give me a screenshot? Thanks!

Comment: Use this [Source Link](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtextended4.4/sxe.html) that will guide you better, safe environment extension need to be installed to create safe environment. Basically will safe guard the device on this this code will run.

Comment: After that it should show you the the Certificate Error where it is failing. `CertificateErrorController::overridable [0x0000000180CF922A+7620650]`